# Username Not echoing in php

Tags: php

I have code that echos the username of the person every time they log in. It worked ONCE, but hasn’t worked since. Please help
Here’s the home.php so far

```php
<?php
include("./inc/header.inc.php");
echo "<br><br><br><br>Hello, ".$user;
echo "<br>Would you like to <a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a>?";
?>
```

And here’s header php code

```php
<?php
session_start();
include("./inc/connect.inc.php");
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
    
}
else {
$user = $_SESSION['user_login'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump($_SESSION)`?

Comment: @Steven where do I put it?

Comment: Literally anywhere after `session_start()`

Comment: @Steven ok thanks I’ll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:
index.php

```
<?php
include("./inc/header.inc.php");
echo "<br><br><br><br>Hello, ".$user;
echo "<br>Would you like to <a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a>?";
```

header.inc.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user_login'] ?? 'Undefined User' ;
```